# Remove unmatched words of string in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a data frame with a row that contains locations. Locations can have various formats, such as:

```
"New York Manhattan UpperEast"
"Upper East, Manhattan, New York"
"Manhattan, New York, Upper East"
"California, San Francisco, Knob Hill"
"San Francisco Knob Hill California"
```

I would like to search for certain words (e.g., all the state names), and remove everything else. The output should be

```
New York
New York
New York
California
California
```

How should I go about it in R?

Comment: You want to remove all other rows that don't have a match? Or you want to remove the portion of the string that doesn't match?

Comment: @CephBirk & Ananda, I updated the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a regular expression from the builtin `state.name` vector that matches any state and apply it using `strapplyc` from the gsubfn package like this:

```
x <- c("New York Manhattan UpperEast",
"Upper East, Manhattan, New York",
"Manhattan, New York, Upper East",
"California, San Francisco, Knob Hill",
"San Francisco Knob Hill California")

library(gsubfn)
states <- paste(state.name, collapse = "|")
strapplyc(x, states, simplify = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
[1] "New York"   "New York"   "New York"   "California" "California"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data frame would look something like this:

```
names <- c("New York Manhattan UpperEast",
           "Upper East, Manhattan, New York",
           "Manhattan, New York, Upper East",
           "California, San Francisco, Knob Hill",
           "San Francisco Knob Hill California")

df <- data.frame(locations =names)
```

You could use some form of grep (This would get the remaining string)

```
df$locations <- gsub("Manhattan|San\ Francisco","",df$locations)
```

But I see you now that you are trying to matched names, this would hopefully work for that use:

```
library(stringr)

df$locations <- str_match(df$locations, "Manhattan|San\ Francisco")
```